# Love2d - how do i unload a file.lua

Tags: lua, filesystems, love2d

I have a menu screen that has an options button. when I click on this button it load the options.lua file perfectly fine.

```
love.filesystem.load( "options.lua" )( ) love.load( )
```

On the option screen I want to add a back button to go back to the main menu. In my head to do this I need to unload the options.lua file.

```
function love.mousepressed( x, y)
    if x > 275 and x < 320 and y > 305 and y < 325 then 

    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Although Paul's answer is one option, you could approach this differently:
You are thinking about this in a way that will cause you a lot of grief, because in Lua, and many other languages loading files is not meant as a way to run code at variable times. Although this might make you change more code than you want, consider creating a variable for GUI States and only draw what you want if that variable has a certain value. Eg:

## Add to your love.load function:

```
    function love.load()
      -- Set the gui state to the defualt ( the main menu )
      guistate = "menu" -- You probably should use an integer, am using a string for the purpose of clarity.
    end
```

## This Goes In the Same Place:

```
function love.mousepressed( x, y)
    if x > 275 and x < 320 and y > 305 and y < 325 then 
      -- The back button is pressed, change the state to the menu.
      guistate = "menu"
    end
end
```

## Add to your love.draw function:

```
function love.draw()
  if guistate = "menu" then
    -- Draw the stuff for your main menu
  elseif guistate = "options" then
    -- Draw the stuff for your options menu.
  end
end
```

## Extras

Also take a peek at these GUI libraries if you are interested:
[Love Frames](https://github.com/KennyShields/LoveFrames), and [Quickie](https://github.com/vrld/Quickie)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to "unload" that file; you can only negate the effect of its loading. You execute the content of `options.lua` in that fragment and if it has something like `a = 5`, to undo this change, you need to save the value of `a` before executing the code in `options.lua` and then restore the value later.

Something like this may work for `a`:

```
local default = {}
default.a = a -- save the current value of a (if any)
love.filesystem.load( "options.lua" )( ) love.load( )
function love.mousepressed( x, y)
    if x > 275 and x < 320 and y > 305 and y < 325 then 
      a = default.a
    end
end
```

You can go through any other value (for example, have a list of names you want to restore). If you want, you can save all values in the global table and restore them later by iterating over `pairs(_G)`. If you deal with tables, rather than simple values, you'll need to use [deep copy](http://lua-users.org/wiki/CopyTable) to save and restore values.

Comment: so I add the top 3 lines of your code to the button, that opens the options.lua page, in main.lua and the rest to the options.lua in the back button. but i get a "attempt to index global 'default' (a nil value)" error